Issues with Locating Features
When I run the command npx cucumber-js, it doesn't find the files, as if they were ignored.
I managed to set up the entire structure and configuration with cucumber.json.
Has anyone experienced this?
Config cucumber.json
Doesn't find the files .feature
I am using Cucumber, Playwright, and TypeScript.
I expected the .feature files to be located to create the steps, but even when I do it manually, they are not found. I edited the tsconfig files, but I admit it's challenging.

Please share a complete example ([mcve]) and post code as text, not images. Thanks.

Yes:
cucumber.json :
"default": {
"dryRun": true,
"formatOptions": {
"snippetInterface": "async-await"
},
"paths": ["./e2etests/tests/features//*.feature"],
"require": ["./e2etests/tests/steps//*.ts"],
"requireModule": ["ts-node/register"],
"format": []
}
When a try to run the npx cucumber-js, the framework doesn't find the .feature file.  No problems, just a warning: "Undefined step". I was doing something similar with this Playlist below: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLT7wPS2WHnwYriuTD8cDNt6KeZ_32QE0f

Thanks. Please [edit] the post to include the info.
